# I want to deploy gitlab repository over aws bean stalk

Tags: gitlab, aws-cli, laravel-5.6, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to add triggers over master branch using gitlab shared worker, but having problems with knowing how the shared worker will connect to aws elastic bean stalk or what user permissions to use and how the aws is going to pull the updates and exec the deployment commands